# docker exec --user db2inst1, unable to find user db2inst1: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: db2, db2-luw, docker, db2-11.5

I'm playing around with docker and db2 but I'm getting into trouble when I try to execute commands as user db2inst1 into a running container. I start the container as (it is 1 line but I split it up for readability):

```
docker run -itd --name mydb2 --privileged=true -p 50000:50000 
  -e LICENSE=accept 
  -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=pelle_paltnacke 
  --mount type=volume,dst=${backupdir},volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,\"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=${addr}\",volume-opt=device=:${device} 
  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd 
  -v /etc/group:/etc/group 
  -v /opt/nya/users/db2inst1:/opt/nya/users/db2inst1 
  -v /home/system/db2fenc1/:/home/system/db2fenc1/ ibmcom/db2
```

Now, if I try to do:

```
docker exec --user db2inst1 -ti mydb2 bash -c "cat /etc/passwd | grep db2inst1"
unable to find user db2inst1: no matching entries in passwd file
```

As root there is no problem:

```
docker exec -ti mydb2 bash -c "cat /etc/passwd | grep db2inst1"
db2inst1:x:422:422:DB2 Instance Administrator 1:/opt/nya/users/db2inst1:/bin/bash
```

and also --user root works fine:

```
docker exec --user root -ti mydb2 bash -c "cat /etc/passwd | grep db2inst1"
db2inst1:x:422:422:DB2 Instance Administrator 1:/opt/nya/users/db2inst1:/bin/bash
```

So I tried with the uid from the mounted passwd file:

```
docker exec --user 422 -ti mydb2 bash -c "cat /etc/passwd | grep db2inst1"
db2inst1:x:422:422:DB2 Instance Administrator 1:/opt/nya/users/db2inst1:/bin/bash
```

/etc/passwd is readable for everyone. Anyhow, using the uid does not get me far:

```
docker exec --user 422 -ti mydb2 bash -c "db2licm -l"
bash: db2licm: command not found
```

so I try with:

```
docker exec --user 422 -ti mydb2 bash -c "whoami; . ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile; 
db2licm -l"
db2inst1
bash: /opt/nya/users/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2licm: Permission denied
```

This is just a couples of commands I ran to demonstrate the problem. Does anyone have an explanation as to why the --user db2inst1 is not able to execute them?

FWIW, I tried without the nfs-mount but I get the same behaviour.

The container itself seems to be working alright. If I spin up the container as above and:

```
#> docker exec -ti mydb2 bash
[root@0ee67959246f /]# mkdir -p /data/db/db2
[root@0ee67959246f /]# chown db2inst1:db2iadm1 /data/db/db2/
[root@0ee67959246f /]# su - db2inst1
[db2inst1@0ee67959246f ~]$ cd /data/backup/db2/wb11/MD000I11/
[db2inst1@0ee67959246f MD000I11]$ db2 "restore db MD000I11 incremental auto taken at 20220307141244 to /data/db/db2 into WD000I11"
DB20000I  The RESTORE DATABASE command completed successfully.
```

EDIT: An interesting observation is:

```
docker exec --user 422 -ti mydb2 bash -c "id"
uid=422(db2inst1) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

docker exec --user 422:422 -ti mydb2 bash -c "id"
uid=422(db2inst1) gid=422(db2iadm1) groups=422(db2iadm1)


docker exec --user 422:422 -ti mydb2 bash -c "whoami; . 
~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile; db2licm -l"

db2inst1
Product name:                     "DB2 Community Edition"
License type:                     "Community"
...
```

Unfortunate:

```
docker exec --user db2inst1:db2iadm1 -ti mydb2 bash -c "id"
unable to find user db2inst1: no matching entries in passwd file
```

Comment: Why do you mount `/etc/passwd` and the instance home directory from the Docker host? Aren't they part of the image?

Comment: passwd, group is to preserve uid etc. I'm trying to replace db2 on the host with a docker version and need to restore the backup(s) from the nfs mounted directory. At the moment I can't recall why I did mount /opt/nya/users/db2inst1, but I got an error when I executed something from within the container. The container it self works, and if I log in to the container and su - db2inst1, I can restore backups etc.

Comment: I never figured this out so I gave up. I ended up creating a container and moved the scripts there. It will be a few ifs and buts in ansible, but it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be unrelated to the Db2 container. I created a Dockerfile with:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.5
```

as it's only content and could repeat the phenomena. I even removed all things but the mount of /etc/passwd and /etc/groups, but --user still fails.

It looks as if --user X becomes uid 1000 in the container, regardless of what username X is, what uid X has in /etc/passwd does not seem to be taken into consideration.

The two options I tried to get around this problem is:

Create a "dummy" user in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ibmcom/db2

RUN groupadd --gid 422 db2iadm1
RUN useradd -u 422 -g db2iadm1 db2inst1
...
```

Or use the uid as an argument to --user:

```
docker exec --user 422:422 -ti mydb2 bash --login -c "db2licm -l"
```

Here I used --login to set up the correct environment.

Using podman should remove much of the hassle I guess